# Geocoder and KML files

Tags: 8, entities

I am using Drupal 8 and I am trying to display a map of a Geofield field, using Leaflet. This part works as expected when I manually enter coordinates into the Geofield.

But problem comes with the geocoding part : I set up a File field to store a KML file. When the Geofield is told to geocode from the KML file field, each time I create or modify a content, two messages are shown :

- a warning about the fact the file "cannot be geocoded",
- an error saying that Drupal "could not find geo data in file" xxx.

Checking the Drupal log adds an interesting information : there is a php warning with a huge message starting with :

> Warning : exif_read_data(test.kml): File not supported in Drupal\geocoder\Geocoder\Provider\File->geocode()

The problem may come from the Geocoder plugin I use for the Geofield geocoding : I can select several plugins in the field management section, all of them apparently dealing with address geocoding, except a "File" plugin. I tried to check only this latter, or all, with the same failing result.

I thought the 'File" Geocoder plugin would be able to deal with KML, GPX... but it may be only for pictures shot containing exif data. Is there a specific plugin for KML files ? And what is the way to make it appear in the Geofield management ?

Anyway, I have tried for hours to find a solution, without any success for any file types (KML, GPX...).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Remi.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but not with leaflet.  It seems the geocoder could not parse kml files with polygons, only points.  I had some railroad routes that worked fine on google earth but not in drupal 8.  I redrew the routes that were "single lines" and it worked fine.